# How do I know when the app is killed in Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, socket.io, expo

I have an expo application that I'm testing on Android. The app connects to a server via socket.io when it starts or when it's in the background. I would like to know when the app is killed or terminated by the user so that I can disconnect the socket connection. How can I know when the expo app is killed or terminated on Android?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really detect when your app is killed by the user or the OS.
You can however detect when the app is backgrounded and foregrounded.
If you want to detect if the app is killed, you will have to use a push notification or background task. If the push notification is received, you can then try to connect to the server.

Comment: I want to keep the socket connection alive when the app is backgrounded. Thus, the problem is knowing when to disconnect the socket...